# How to load next value from my Array into my function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've been trying all night now and I can't get it to work.
I'm trying to get the value from an Array into a script I've found on the web.
The script loads every 10 seconds a new page, but I'd like to load a html-page from my Array and after the 10 seconds it should load the next one from my Array.
Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Much appreciated!
Leon

```
function pageSwitch() { 

    // MY PAGES ////////
    let myArray = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html"];


    $parent.find('.page-current').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).html($parent.find('.page-new').html());
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);

        nextPage = // HERE NEXT PAGE ////////
        if (nextPage.length > -1) {

            $fuse.width(fuseContainerWidth);
            animateFuse();
        } else {
            /***** check this ******/
            $parent.fadeOut();
        }
        $parent.find('.page-new').load(nextPage);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numberOfMilliseconds = 1000;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.forEach((item, index) =>
  setTimeout(() => console.log(item), numberOfMilliseconds * index)
)
```

Comment: Hi there.

Thank you for your anwser. But I've tried to implement it, but it doesn't work for me (cause of my lack of Javascript... :-/).

What I want is that every 10 seconds the next item of my Array should be loaded in the 'nextPage' this line:

`$parent.find('.page-new').load(nextPage);`

Comment: just replace `arr` with `myArray` and `console.log()` with `load()`

Comment: Hi, thnx again for your anwser. But I don't get it... Sorry.

Where in my function do I put your code?

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```js
const numberOfMilliseconds = 1000;

function pageSwitch() {

  // MY PAGES ////////
  let myArray = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html"];

  myArray.forEach((nextPage, index) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      $parent.find('.page-current').fadeOut(numberOfMilliseconds, function() {
        $(this).html($parent.find('.page-new').html());
        $(this).fadeIn(numberOfMilliseconds);
          if (nextPage.length > -1) {
            $fuse.width(fuseContainerWidth);
            animateFuse();
          } else {
            /***** check this ******/
            $parent.fadeOut();
          }
        $parent.find('.page-new').load(nextPage);
      });
    }, numberOfMilliseconds * index)
  )


}
```

Comment: Hi there!

Thnx for your help! I'l give this a try!

Leon